# Webpage scrolls when keyboard pops up

Tags: javascript, ios, css, chat

I've noticed that when I am on my ipad or iphone and I open up the chatbox on my site and start to type, the webpage behind the chatbox will scroll back to the top of the site and not stay where I scrolled down. My website is www.leormanelis.com. Does not seem to happen on android devices. Does anyone know a fix?

Video - https://screencast.com/t/uiWdL39Qg6

Comment: Can you post your code please? We can only help if we can diagnose the problem! For reference, here is a link to how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your scroll to top button is under the chat button this is from Safari on Mac, you need to make sure the CSS of the 2 buttons doesn't overlap each other

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHvK9.png)